# How to point apache to use latest PHP?

Tags: magento2, php, apache

Ok, here is an issue.

My website was running great. And then it just somehow shows this

> Magento supports PHP 7.1.3 or later.

I'v checked the Terminal and it was 5.6.something and I upgrade it.

Now the terminal shows it is 7.4.16, but my website still shows this message when I try to access it with browser.

When i do php --version command

> `PHP 7.4.16 (cli) (built: Apr  2 2021 04:55:39) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies`

Now how to fix this, cause my website "thinks" I'm still with uncompatable PHP?
I'v restarted apache 5 times. No result

Pls check http://apex11.com/

Comment: Please check your PHP version in phpinfo file. I think your PHP version changed in CLI but not changed for the frontend. You need to change for the frontend as well.

Comment: Thank you dude. Just tell me in details how to do that?. Where can I find this phpinfo file?

Comment: Run below command and then check:

Comment: sudo a2enmod php7.4

Comment: sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: Create a PHP file like info.php and then add <?php phpinfo();, and then open it to the browser. Then check which PHP version is working.